# Selenium does not detect version of Chrome Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Yesterday the version of Google Chrome was updated to 109.0.5414.75 and with it also Web Driver, the problem is that when I try to run Selenium it gives me an error because the script continues to detect version 107 of Web Driver despite the fact that I already updated the executable in question

GOOGLE CHROME VERSION

[image]

WEBDRIVER VERSION FROM CMD

[image]

ERROR WHILE RUNNING SERVICE

[image]

What could I do to solve this problem?

############  EDIT 1 ##################

this is the code for my web scrapper

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# configure webdriver
operadriver = "chromedriver.exe"
options = Options()
options.binary_location = 'chromedriver.exe'
options.headless = True  # hide GUI

options.add_argument("start-maximized")  # ensure window is full-screen


# configure chrome browser to not load images and javascript
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()



driver = webdriver.Chrome(operadriver, options=options, 
chrome_options=chrome_options )

driver.get(url)

pb = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//*")
lista = list()
    x = 0

for p in pb:
    if str(p.tag_name) == 'input' or str(p.tag_name) == 'select' or 
str(p.tag_name) == 'textarea' or str(p.tag_name) == 'button' :
        x+=1
        #print (x)
        
         lista.append([x,p.tag_name,p.get_attribute('type'),p.get_attribute('id'),str(p.get_attribute('class')).split(" ")])
        if x > 100:
            break
        if lista == None:
            lista.appen("no hay formularios en la pagina")
    else:
        continue

driver.quit()
print (lista)
```

Imagen from Folder where file and python script are located

[image]

PD: I checked the path as the user
Mahsum Akbas told me but I did not find a path that points to that folder

Comment: You need to uninstall chrome driver 107 and install chrome driver 109 https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: You should add you code for us to see what you are doing. Are you giving it the right path?

Comment: If you set address of chromedriver in PATH variable, it may gives that error. Be sure old driver is not exist anymore.

Comment: I have edited the information as requested

Comment: Thanks to Mahsum Akbas comment I was able to see where the error originated or at least what I consider was failing, since the Web Driver made a copy of the older Chromedriver.exe in the root folder of python 3.10. I only had to update it with the new file and problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mahsum Akbas comment I was able to see where the error originated or at least what I consider was failing, since the Web Driver made a copy of the older Chromedriver.exe in the root folder of python 3.10. I only had to update it with the new file and problem solved